# Two divs on the same line if there is space

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm currently trying to save vertical space on my webpage and I'm trying to figure out if there's an elegant solution to my problem.

I've created a 'options' component in angular that takes two optional templates. Here's the relevant code:

```
  <div class="options-body">
    <div *ngIf="filterContent?.templateRef">
      <span class="option-title">Filters</span>
      <div class="filter-container">
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="filterContent!.templateRef"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="actions-container" *ngIf="actionContent?.templateRef">
      <span class="option-title">Actions</span>
      <div>
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="actionContent!.templateRef"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that sometimes the templates are small in width, such as in this example:[image: small width example]

and sometimes it's not:
[image: large width example]

I'm wondering if I could make the two divs inline if the width is small enough while maintaining the functionality the same (Here's an example of desired solution for small width divs that i whipped up with paint):
[image: desired small width example]

Comment: [css flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)? or [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)?

Comment: I don't think media queries would work here, as the reason for this issue is not because of the characteristics of the different screens, but because the component doesn't know about it's contents.

Would love a more concrete example regarding flexbox

Comment: I wrote a little example. The link above about css flex, is a good link. It's a hard to understand but I think it worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

use 50% fixed width for both div. Or use bootstrap row column to keep equal the both divs

Comment: If I would use 50% fixed width, then the second example would not work

Comment: so, you can use display flex and justify-content-between. I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

using css flex

```
.content{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap; //<--this is the key
  justify-content:flex-start
  
}
.wrapper-input{
  display:block;
  margin-right:1rem;
}
.wrapper-input label{
    display:block;
}
```

e.g.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper-input">
     <label>one</label>
     <input>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-input">
     <label>two</label>
     <input>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-input">
     <label>three</label>
     <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mrtwc7?file=src%2Fmain.ts)